# Чи варто використовувати іменники - лигайшворінь, лигайшпага?

Tags: іменники

На сайті [OnlineCorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0/) пропонують

> Для урізноманітнення мовлення замініть іменник шаблековтач на варіант:
> лигайшворінь, лигайшпага.

[image]

Проте в словниках слів-заміників немає, а є лише шпагоковтач (СУМ-11).

> [ШАБЛЕКОВТА́Ч](http://sum.in.ua/s/shablekovtach), а, чол. Штукар, що показує фокус з ковтанням шаблі.

Чи варто використовувати лигайшворінь, лигайшпага?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ця порада йде із «Секретів української мови» Святослава Караванського ([видання 1994 року](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Karavanskyy_Sviatoslav/Sekrety_ukrainskoi_movy/), [видання 2009 року](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Karavanskyy_Sviatoslav/Sekrety_ukrainskoi_movy_vyd_2009/)):

> …Українську мову в УССР засмічувано кальками-копіями з російської мови. Читаючи видання УССР, можна зустріти чимало «винаходів» з кухні Інституту мовознавства АН УССР, керованого академіком Бєлодєдом та його учнями:
>
> шаблековтач (1)
>       струмообертач
>       шлаконагромаджувач.
>
> Чи це живі слова? Чи хтось колись вживав їх, вживає, чи буде вживати? Це треба було б спитати у тих, хто засмітив такими «перлами» словники, підручники, наукову й технічну літературу.
>
> Простежмо, як постало слово шаблековтач.
>
> Немає жодного сумніву — це копія російського слова шпагоглотатель. Для росіянина слово шпагоглотатель звучить нормально з багатьох причин. Воно відповідає російським словотворчим моделям, де віддієслівна частина глотатель на другому місці, — це раз, воно має легку для вимови звукову структуру А-О-О-А-Е з жіночим наголосом — це два. Додам, що слово глотатель само по собі існує в російській мові, і отже, вся сполука цілком зрозуміла для вуха росіянина.
>
> Щодо українського слова шаблековтач, то воно не відповідає українським словотворчим моделям, а слово ковтач само по собі в нашій мові не існує.
>
> У творених українцями складних словах віддієслівна частина стоїть на першому місці:
>
> варивода (2)
>       вернигора
>       вертихвіст
>       загнибіда
>       закрутиголова
>       котигорошок
>       паливода
>       пройдисвіт
>       перекотиполе
>       скализуб
>       хапокниш.
>
> Головна перевага форм (2) у тім, що вони мають один або й два додаткових півнаголоси (коти́горо́шок, приши́й-коби́лі-хві́ст), що сприяє і вимові і засвоєнню слова.
>
> Маючи модель (2) за зразок, поміркуймо, як належить по-українському назвати особу, що ковтає шаблі або шпаги (шпади).  Тут можливо кілька варіянтів:
>
> ковтайшабля, лигайшабля, ковтайшпага, лигайшпага, ковтайшпада, лигайшпада
>
> Кожен з цих варіянтів, як на мене, краще звучить від незграбного шаблековтача. Щоб надати українського забарвлення усій формі, варто у другій частині складного слова замість шаблі вжити шворінь:
>
> ковтайшворінь, лигайшворінь
>
> Отже, ми маємо аж вісім форм, з котрих треба вибрати найвлучнішу. Мені здається, що такою формою є форма лигайшворінь, але читач може сам вибрати, що, на його смак, найкраще вписується в українську мовну тональність, або й запропонувати свій варіянт до шаблековтача, форми неживої і неконкурентоздатної.
>
> Наведений приклад наочно показує, що мова, яка «здирає» лексичні форми з усталених зразків інших мов, компромітує сама себе карикатурністю здертих форм, обертається на мову-жебрака, на блідий варіянт «досконалої та розвиненої» мови.
>
> Очевидно й те, що для успішного словотворення треба глибше аналізувати наявні, випробувані часом зразки українського словотвору, які відкривають невичерпні можливості для мовної творчости.
>
> Описаний словотвір дозволяє підшукати варіянти і до кальок (1):
>
> (Калька — Українська форма)
>       струмообертач — верниструм або крутиструм
>       шлаконагромаджувач — збирайшлак або стягайшлак
>
> Річ ясна, що можливі й інші розв'язки. Той, хто гадає, що українська мова має обмежені можливості словотвору і тому має вдаватися до калькування, очевидно, глибоко помиляється. У дальшому викладі буде розглянуто кілька «невикористаних можливостей» українського словотвору, ігнорованих в УССР через антиукраїнську політику комуністичного режиму.

Але при всій повазі до Святослава Караванського — ніде в книжках (Google Книги, [корпус GRAC-3](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac3&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=[word=%22(%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9|%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B9)%D1%88.*%22])) я не бачу реального вжитку жодного із запропонованих слів (ковтайшабля, ковтайшворінь, ковтайшпага, ковтайшпада, лигайшабля, лигайшворінь, лигайшпага, лигайшпада; окрім, власне, посилання на вищенаведену книгу Караванського і декількох джерел, що безпосередньо базуються на ній: вищенаведеної статті OnlineCorrector, [статті «Українська мова далі уподібнюється російській» у Gazeta.ua](//gazeta.ua/articles/istoriya-movi/_ukrayinska-mova-dali-upodibnyuyetsya-rosijskij/464685) й [допису на форумі СЛОВНИКа.ua](http://forum.slovnyk.ua/index.php?showtopic=35&pid=248#firstpost)).

Отже вищенаведені 8 варіантів  (ковтайшабля, ковтайшворінь, ковтайшпага, ковтайшпада, лигайшабля, лигайшворінь, лигайшпага, лигайшпада) є власним словотвором Святослава Караванського. Це його погляд на те, як мало б бути (навіть розділ, що містить цитату, називається «Невикористані можливості»), але реально українські автори до цієї поради досі (майже) не дослухалися. Чи дослухатися Вам — вирішувати Вам.

Comment: Так сама ідея зі статті правильна чи надумана? Бо якщо вона правильно, то тут нема чого думати - треба виправляти помилки.

Comment: @Yola, ну, я не можу відповісти на це запитання об'єктивно. Мені здається, ближче до надуманої. Але навіть якщо ідея про більшу логічність слова _А_ за слово _Б_ правильна — це ще не означає, що треба обов'язково вживати _А_ — мова для того, щоб тебе розуміли, а не для вправ з логіки (принаймні я тричі подумаю, перш ніж уживати слово, незрозуміле іншим, можливо вживатиму його спочатку у випадках, де це не критично і/або його значення видно з контексту).

Comment: якщо творення слів буде нелогічним, то мовою буде складно користуватись. Набагато легше запам"ятовувати слова, якщо вони піддаються певним правилам. Це ж не шифр якійсь де потрібна плутанина.

Comment: @Yola, з одного боку — так. З іншого боку — різні люди можуть одну й ту саму ситуацію підводити під різні закономірності, тому логічним для однієї й тої самої ситуації за їхніми поглядами буде різне. А усунення всіх неоднозначностей (розв'язування всіх конфліктів між закономірностями) у мові, можливо, призведе до стрімкого збільшення її складності.

Comment: Лигайшворінь образніше й відбиває нашу питому рису. Тому як простий мовець гадаю слід використовувати перший варіянт, хоча слово зрештою за фаховими мовознавцями.