# Чи варто замінювати слово "мультфільм"

Tags: вживання-слів, відповідник

Словник української мови в 11 томах

> ***[Мультфільм](http://sum.in.ua/s/muljtfiljm)*** у, чол. Скорочення: мультиплікаційний фільм.

На сайті [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/multfilm) пропонують декілька слів-заміників ***"мультфільм"***:

> - малюванка (найбільше голосів)
> - оживанка
> - мальованка
> - рухорис

В [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=49525&page=1563) та [СУМ -11](http://sum.in.ua/s/maljovanka) є лише одне слово-заміник, але зовсім іншого значення

> ***Мальованка*** и, ж. Спідниця з полотна, розмальованого кустарним способом

Який варіант краще обрати? Чи варто замінювати широко відоме та вживане слово  *"мультфільм"* на вигадане нове? Чи існує нормативний відповідник?

Comment: Зазначу, шчо загалом розповсьуџеніше поньатье по сьвіту — _анімованиј фільм_ (_анімоване кіно_) чи просто _анімаціја_. Посеред південсловјан також зустрічајеть сьа [_цртани филм_](//sr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Цртани_филм), тобто [мальованиј](https://pl.wiktionary.org/wiki/crtati). Особисто вживају _рухавка_, але це не затверџене, або зі [застарілим значіньам](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=рухавка&highlight=on), до котрого доперти непросто. Дльа фізкультурних је вже [руханка](//google.com.ua/search?q=руханка&lr=-lang_ru&safe=off). Слово _рухорис_ цьікаве і непогане.

Comment: @follower у зв'язку з [цим](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/5042/%D0%A7%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0) питанням, чому не *рисорух*?

Comment: @Yola Бо тут _рис_ не від _рисувати_, а _рисунок_, јак і багато подібних слів: _правопис_, де _пис_ не від _писати_, а _писанье_ (_письмо_).